# Rails (6.1) app not finding generated Webpacker assets in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have a Rails 6 app that I am using with Webpacker.  Things seem to work fine in development, but I am having issues getting it deployed into production correctly.  I have a page that attempts to include a Webpacker pack:

```
= provide(:title, 'Home')
= provide(:page_id, "home")

div[id='root']
  = javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag 'application'
```

However, in production, I get these errors in the console:

```
GET [MY_SITE]/packs/js/application-9bceb4887f19c44c6d14.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

When I log into the instance though, I can see that I do have a file called `application-9bceb4887f19c44c6d14.js` in my `public/packs/js` directory.  So it looks like my asset compilation is happening.  I just don't understand why my app seems to not be able to locate that asset.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I had to change this line in my `config/environments/production.js` file from

`config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?` to
`config.public_file_server.enabled = true`